# HiveQL - Grouping Count

Tags: hive, count, grouping, hiveql

I'm a newbie here and still facing a lot of problems in HiveQL, need to consult with you all. I have a table named Vote Table, and I'd like to count the "yes" vote for A,B,C,D (sorry I wasn't able to post the image, so I sent it as a link instead).

[Vote_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr8nS.png)

But here I'd like to only join the count of A1,A2,A3,A4 together; and for B,C will still be counted individually. The output I'm expecting would be

[Result_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDHoW.png)

What I've tried is

```
select
type,
count(
  case 
          when type = 'A1' and vote = 'yes' then 1
          when type = 'A2' and vote = 'yes' then 1
          when type = 'A3' and vote = 'yes' then 1
          when type = 'A4' and vote = 'yes' then 1
          else vote = 'yes' then 1
)
from vote_table
where …
group by type
```

I've also tried this way

```
if (type in ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4') and vote = 'yes' then count(*) else (if (vote = 'yes' then count(*)))) as cnt_yes
```

But both don't work. So, I'd like to consult it with the experts here, is there any better way in doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Please do not add "SOLVED" to the titles of questions. Simply marking an answer as being the solution is enough.

Comment: @NikosC. Hi Nikos! Ok, got it! Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by calculated type: `case when type in ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4') then 'A' else type end`

```
select
      case when type in ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4') then 'A' else type end as type,
      sum(case when vote = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)                     as number_of_vote
 from vote_table
where ...
group by case when type in ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4') then 'A' else type end
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply, I'm trying your solution and waiting for the result, hope it will work for me! Btw, I have some small questions:
1. If in the 'case when' clause I dont't use the 'else 0' part, will it affect the result?
2. If 'sum' I change it to 'count', the result would be the same, right?
Sorry maybe these are stupid questions, but I just want to have a good grasp in the basic knowledge since I'm still learning it~ Thanksss~~

Comment: @Claire CASE will return NULL in case vote!='yes' and COUNT will count only not NULLs. In case all votes were 'no', result of count will be NULL. You may want to transform resulting NULL to 0 maybe using NVL, etc. Though for your exactly dataset it will work fine.

Comment: Ah! I see! Thanks so much for your explanation!